# simplifying boolean expression in minterm

Tags: boolean-algebra

i am trying to simply the equation and stuck. Sum symbol(2,4,6,7). It means $$  F = A'BC' + AB'C' + ABC' + ABC $$ $$ = A'BC' + AB'C' + AB(C' + C) $$ $$ = A'BC' + AB'C' + AB  $$ After the last equation  part, I haven't gone on. Did I choose wrong way for  the simplification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}F &= A'BC' + AB'C' + \color{blue}{ABC'} + ABC\\~\\&=A'BC' + AB'C' + \color{blue}{ABC' +ABC' +ABC' } + ABC\\~\\ &= (A'BC'+\color{blue}{ABC'}) +( AB'C' + \color{blue}{ABC'} ) + (ABC+ \color{blue}{ABC'} )  \\~\\&=BC' + AC' + AB\end{align}$$

Comment: I couldn't think it. How did you think?

Comment: Haha I just noticed ABC' sharing two variables with all other terms

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Karnaugh map to do it.

Comment: It is forbidden for now. I know it is a piece of cake.